# How to calculate total weight of all components in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm testing SQL query which calculates the total weight of a components. These are the tables structure:

Here I store the key of the parent component and the child component:

```
-- CREATE TABLES SECTION -------------------------------------------------

-- TABLE COMPONENT

CREATE TABLE COMPONENT(
  COMPONENTID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  FKCOMPONENTID NUMBER,
  COMPONENTSTATSID INTEGER NOT NULL
)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE COMPONENT

ALTER TABLE COMPONENT ADD CONSTRAINT COMPONENTID PRIMARY KEY (COMPONENTID)
```

Here I store the id of the component and the weight:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPONENTSTATS(
  COMPONENTSTATSID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  COMPONENTTYPEID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(200 ) NOT NULL,
  SERIALNUMBER VARCHAR2(150 ),
  WEIGHTKG NUMBER(14,4),
  SIZEWEIGHTMILIM NUMBER(14,4),
)
/

-- ADD KEYS FOR TABLE COMPONENTSTATS

ALTER TABLE COMPONENTSTATS ADD CONSTRAINT COMPONENTSTATSID PRIMARY KEY (COMPONENTSTATSID)
/
```

I want to create tree with components and using SQL query to calculate the total weight of all components. I made this SQL query:

```
select c.componentid, nvl(cs.weightkg, 0) as componentkg,
 (case 
    when exists (select 1 from component where fkcomponentid = c.componentid) then
      (select sum(nvl(cs.weightkg, 0)) as kg FROM  component a, componentstats cs  where a.fkcomponentid is not null and cs.componentstatsid = a.componentstatsid and a.fkcomponentid = c.componentid)
 end) as childrenkg
 from component c, componentstats cs  
 where 
 cs.componentstatsid = c.componentstatsid
 and componentid = ?
 order by c.componentid;
```

But for some reason I cannot get the proper result. I only get the first children of the first parent. The goal is to use the COMPONENT table to get the all children and sub children and to calculate the weight.

Can you help me to find where I'm wrong?

Comment: Is FKCOMPONENTID a foreign key to COMPONENT? You haven't defined this recursive foreign key.

Comment: Yes but I have implemented FKCOMPONENTID to be a foreign key to COMPONENTSTATSID

Comment: @Peter Penzov, Check Oracle scott.emp built in table for example of how to define recursive foreign key. Then use hierarchical query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query in Oracle to return the tree of components, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

```
select componentid,
         (select sum(cs.weightkg)
            from component c2, componentstats cs
           where c2.componentstatsid = cs.componentstatsid
               start with c2.componentid = c1.componentid
         connect by prior c2.componentid = c2.fkcomponentid) sum_weightkg
from component c1
start with c1.fkcomponentid is null
connect by prior componentid = fkcomponentid;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/def0e/2

Comment: Yes, it working but I need to modify it a little bit: I want to pass the id of the parent as parameter. Where I have to insert it? And I need to get the result as total number.

Comment: It's just a SQL statement, so you can add a where clause right after the from clause. In this case, add `where c1.componentid = <yourvalue>`.